# Split file with awk numerating output files with double digits

Tags: awk

I have this text file

```
@
text text text

text text text
@
text text text
@
text text text text
text text text

text text text
```

which I can split in multiple files at `@` with

```
awk '/@/{n++;close(filename)}{filename = "part" n ".txt"; print >filename }'  text.txt
```

Still I would like to improve the command so to avoid including `@` as first line of each new file: I want the first line of each file to be directly `text text text`.

Also I have few problem with the numeration of the files. The new files follow this numeration: `part1.txt`, `part2.txt`, ... , `part10.txt` but this create a problem when ordering the file because `part10.txt` will be ordered before `part2.txt`. Is it possible to have files numerate with two digits `part01.txt` and `part02.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk '/@/{n++;close(filename)} !/@/{filename = sprintf("part%02d.txt", n); print >filename; }' text.txt
```

Or a bit cleaner, with stricter pattern matching and without duplicating the pattern:

```
awk '{ if ($0 == "@") {n++;close(filename)} else {filename = sprintf("part%02d.txt", n); print >filename; }}' text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to test more than once.  Use `next` to skip the `@` row.

```
awk '/^@$/{n++;close(filename);next} {print >sprintf("part%02d.txt", n)}' text.txt
```